# How to detect that no one is writing to a file in Linux?

Tags: linux, file, inotify

I am wondering, is there a simple way to tell whether another entity has a certain file open for writing? I don't have time to use iNotify continuously to wait for any current writer to finish writing. I need to do an intermittent check.
Thanks.

Comment: does this help: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/117115-check-if-file-opened-reading-unix.html

Comment: You can't really use this information in a non-racy manner - even if some function tells you that the file is not currently being written, that information may already be out-of-date by the time your process acts on it.  If you control both processes, use `fcntl()` advisory locking.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly are you doing where you "don't have time to use iNotify continuously"?  First, you should be using the `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` flag so that iNotify just make one notification when the file gets closed after being written.  Using it continuously makes no sense.  Second, if your timing is that critical, I'm thinking writing to a file isn't your ideal solution.  Do you control the first writer?  Do you have to worry about anything else writing to the file after the first writer closes it?

Answer (score 1):

`lsof` LiSts Open Files.  `fuser` also works similarly (File USER), by telling you which user is using the file.

See:  http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/23/16-Introduction-to-lsof-and-fuser/

Comment: That's true but I'm hoping to do it programmatically. To use lsof I'd have to call system() etc and that would take too long.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be wanting to use a library-style interface, and not system, see [ofl-lib.c](http://pam-mount.git.sf.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=pam-mount/pam-mount;a=blob;f=src/ofl-lib.c;hb=v2.5). (It's really just having removed everything but the main function from the [ofl](http://www.google.de/search?q=hxtools) program itself.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do so easily in the general case, and even if you could, you cannot use the information in a non-racy manner (see caf's comment).

So I'd say, redesign your application so you do not need to know.